# Inheritance vs composition in JPA

Tags: jpa, inheritance, composition

A legacy application persistence is based on JPA. There is an entity, People, mapped to the database table **People**.
Now a subset of all the rows in People needs some additional fields.
One possible solution is to use jpa inheritance and create a new entity, suppose **EmployeedPeople**, which extends **People**.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class People {

...

@Entity(name = “EmployeedPeople”)
public class EmployeedPeople extends  People {
```

Alternatively I can use unidirectional one to one relationship

```
@Entity(name = “EmployeedPeople”)
public class EmployeedPeople {
...
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private People commonPersonData;
```

I thought about a third way too: the new entity is based on a database view which joins **People** table with **EmployeedData** table.
This last approach is good for reading **EmployeedPeople** but impractical for inserting and updating because I have to work with different entities (**People** and **EmployeedData**).

Which criteria can help in choosing the strategy ? 
Which are the pros and cons of each solutions ?

In internet I have already found the following guide which [compares the inheritance strategies](https://thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) and this one [on composition](https://thoughts-on-java.org/composition-vs-inheritance-jpa-hibernate/) but my ideas are not clear yet.